# SQL Server OPENROWSET error reading bcp file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to transfer table data from one SQL Server to another and wanting to use the `bcp` utility for it. This is purely to transfer data between two identical schemas, but I'm not able to use something like SSDT; I need something that can be scriptable and portable so it can be run by others with just SQL server and SSMS access.

I am generating a native output file and format file like so:

```
$> bcp database.TableName OUT c:\data\bcp\TableName.bcp -T -N -S SQLINSTANCE

$> bcp database.TableName format nul -f c:\data\bcp\TableName.fmt -T -N
```

Then in Management Studio I am trying to in turn read the files like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\data\bcp\TableName.bcp',
                FORMATFILE = 'c:\data\bcp\TableName.fmt') AS t1
```

But am getting this error:

> The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 6, column 19. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

I have followed this process before successfully, and it works for other tables.  But I'm running into issue with this table. The column mentioned is of datatype `nvarchar(max)`. I can inspect what I think is the "problem" record in the source data and it's just a very long string but I don't see anything else special about it.

Is there something else I should be doing when generating the format file or what else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only exporting for the purpose of importing to another SQL Server, native format is the way to go. And is this case you don't need to use format files. Just do a native export and import.

Note you are specifying a capital `-N` and that's not native. Native is lower `-n`.

You should export using something like:

```
bcp database.Schema.TableName OUT c:\data\bcp\TableName.bcp -T -n -S SQLINSTANCE
```

Then on the importing side I sugest using BULK IMPORT, which don't need a format file for native at all:

```
BULK INSERT TargetDB.dbo.TargetTable
FROM 'c:\data\bcp\TableName.bcp'
WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'native');
```

If you can't use BULK INSERT and must absolutely go for OPENROWSET, you need a format file. bcp can generate that for you, but again, lower case `-n`:

```
bcp database.Schema.TableName format nul -f c:\data\bcp\TableName.fmt -T -n -S SQLINSTANCE
```

Now your `OPENROWSET` should work.

Comment: Thanks. I still ended up getting the same error when trying to use `OPENROWSET`, but just on the one table.  `BULK INSERT` did function correctly, though. Best I can figure is there must be something in the generated format file that is affecting the reading of the `nvarchar(max)` field, or the length of the problem record really is too long.